# Animating UIStackView subviews causes layout issues

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, uistackview

I have a UIStackView with several arranged views inside, which can be shown and hidden using buttons.
I animate the changes by:
- initially setting the alpha to 0 and isHidden = true of some subviews
- in an animate block, switch which subview has alpha = 1 and isHidden = false

I created a playground to show the issue: https://gist.github.com/krummler/d0e8db8cb037ae7202f7d801d3114111

In short, this works fine for two views: switching between ANY two subviews works fine. When pressing a third, the view collapses and refuses to come back. After that, showing subviews becomes a mess. Interestly, it does *not* show this behaviour when animations are commented out.

My questions:
- Am I missing something or did I hit some bug in UIKit?
- How can I work around this or is there a better wat to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Could you please include a code snippet as a part of the question?

Comment: @GabeSpound The sample code is quite large, it's a playground in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say how UIStackView is implemented, but it may be attempting to update its layout when `isHidden` is modified even though the value is not actually changing.

Perhaps this is a UIKit bug, but as a workaround you can modify your `resetSubviews(to:)` implementation so that it only sets `isHidden` when the state is actually changing.

```swift
    private func resetSubviews(to view: UIView) {
        view1.alpha = view == view1 ? 1 : 0
        view2.alpha = view == view2 ? 1 : 0
        view3.alpha = view == view3 ? 1 : 0
        view4.alpha = view == view4 ? 1 : 0

        let updateIsHiddenForView = { (viewToUpdate: UIView) in
            let isHidden = view != viewToUpdate
            if isHidden != viewToUpdate.isHidden {
                viewToUpdate.isHidden = isHidden
            }
        }
        updateIsHiddenForView(view1)
        updateIsHiddenForView(view2)
        updateIsHiddenForView(view3)
        updateIsHiddenForView(view4)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, interestingly, this behaviour doesn't appear when I comment out the animations. Either way, this helps to avoid the issue, thanks!